# Using function from another file in React Component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have the a `React` component called `Hero`. I'm using the `anime.js` lib to add some effects to my title.

My animations are stored in a file called `animations.js` which looks like this:

```js
import anime from 'animejs/lib/anime.es.js';

export function letterStagger(){

  console.log("test");

  var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.hero__title .hero__title-letters');
  console.log(textWrapper); // returns null
  textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='hero__title-letter'>$&</span>");

  anime.timeline({loop: true})
  .add({
    targets: '.hero__title .hero__title-letter',
    translateY: ["1.1em", 0],
    translateZ: 0,
    duration: 750,
    delay: (el, i) => 50 * i
  }).add({
    targets: '.hero__title',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000
  });
}
```

Now, I'm trying to run this function in my `Hero` component, like so:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { letterStagger } from "../../utils/animations";

class Hero extends React.Component{
  render(){

    return (
      <section className="hero">
        <h1 className="hero__title">
          <span className="hero__title-inner">
            <span className="hero__title-letters">This is the title</span>
          </span>
        </h1>
      </section>
    )
    
    letterStagger();

  }
}

export default Hero;
```

I have no compilation errors, but I have a warning which says `Unreachable code` on `letterStagger()`.

If I have `letterStagger()` after `render()` I get errors in relation to `textContent`. When I run `console.log(textWrapper);`, it returns null, which makes me think the function is running before the text is found (which is why I've tried adding `letterStagger()` at the end of `render()`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You are getting an unreachable code warning because `letterStagger()` is after the return statement of the render method. You have to place `letterStagger()` inside a life cycle like `componentDidMount` or `useEffect` If using hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t manipulate DOM directly in React, it can lead to unexpected behavior. Use refs instead https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 0):

You can approach to children of a Component only when the component has been mounted. It means, you should use a method of the Component's life cycle. In your case it is `componentDidMount`

So the working code will be as follows:

```js
class Hero extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    letterStagger();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="hero">
        <h1 className="hero__title">
          <span className="hero__title-inner">
            <span className="hero__title-letters">This is the title</span>
          </span>
        </h1>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```